# Is Sarah M. Robinson's mother Anna Strong really Eleanor Denton?

Tags: death-records, grave-marker, michigan

The [1885 Detroit, Michigan, death certificate of Sarah M. Robinson](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N3XZ-P5B) (b. c. 1812, New York) lists her as the daughter of James Strong and Anna Strong, both born in New York. She [is buried in Elmwood Cemetery, Detroit](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/99550217), as is James A. Strong, at least [according to a Find a Grave entry](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/143123386/james-a-strong) (no gravestone photo).

According to [the 1850 federal census records for Detroit](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MF8R-5LZ), James was born in New York and lived with Elloner Strong (whom I believe was his wife Eleanor Denton). The household also includes Julia Welder (whom I believe is their daughter, Juliet Wilder). [The 1860 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MWD6-ZQG) shows him still living with Juliette Weilter [sic]. [According to Find a Grave](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/99537782/juliet-denton-wilder), Sarah is buried near Juliet D. (Strong) Wilder. [Juliet's 1888 Detroit death record](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FHRH-L4B) shows her as having been born in New York c. 1811 but does not list her parents.

I am trying to figure out if Julia and Sarah are sisters, which may hinge on whether the Anna Strong in Sarah's death record is really Eleanor Strong.